# Prognosis for disowned X11 program. Can I un-disown it?

Tags: x11, disown

I have a disowned X11 program, running under my user account. I started it during an SSH session that was disconnected due to a network problem.

I'd like to continue working with it, if possible. Can I un-disown it somehow? Perhaps change its server? It doesn't have a TTY attached.

Comment: When I logged in at the console, the process was still there. Once the network was working again, I logged out, then logged back in over SSH. And now it isn't there any more. So... that solves that conundrum, I suppose. I'd still be interested in any suggestions.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but in the future, you can use things like [Nomachine NX](https://www.nomachine.com/) to run X11 apps which can be detached & reattached on other sessions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use try using [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr).

Comment: The question is about a program using X, not using a terminal.